# PHP PUT data to Json in RESTful API

Tags: php, json, api, rest

I have received a string like this:

```
    id=123&nid=28&ntype=content&text=This%20is%20a%20note
```

I need to change this data to JSON. 
Is there any in-built function in PHP or some custom function?

Comment: http://www.php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this...

```
$get_string = "id=123&nid=28&ntype=content&text=This%20is%20a%20note";
parse_str($get_string, $get_array);
echo json_encode($get_array);
```

You will get output like this...

```
{"id":"123","nid":"28","ntype":"content","text":"This is a note"}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$tmp = parse_str($string);
echo json_encode($tmp);
```